# I'm using an array to update MYSQL database but the ID dosn't match

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm looping through an array in node JS to update MYSQL database but the array starts at 0 and my auto incrementing database starts at 1. This obviusly offsets my whole data base by 1 row. Would much appreciate a solution to this. I'm using the sequelize NPM package aswell. Thanks in advance.

```
function ejsoutput(json){
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 10;i++){
    
    const updatedRank = json.entries[i].rank;
    const updatedRating = json.entries[i].rating;
    const updatedName = json.entries[i].character.name;
    const updatedRealm = json.entries[i].character.realm.slug;
    const updatedFaction = json.entries[i].faction.type;
    const updatedPlayed = json.entries[i].season_match_statistics.played;
    const updatedWon = json.entries[i].season_match_statistics.won;
    const updatedLost = json.entries[i].season_match_statistics.lost;

    Product.findByPk(i)
    .then(product => {
      product.rank = updatedRank;
      product.rating = updatedRating;
      product.name = updatedName;
      product.realm = updatedRealm;
      product.faction = updatedFaction;
      product.played = updatedPlayed;
      product.won = updatedWon;
      product.lost = updatedLost;
      return product.save();
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log('UPDATED PRODUCT')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Why don't you set `var i = 1` instead

Comment: You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled.  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @omidh this would skip 0 in the array

Comment: Try `Product.findByPk(i + 1)` instead.

Comment: I knew it would be simple. Thank you @omidh

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to the code.

```
Product.findByPk(i + 1)
```